# Passar um texto para um EditText

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para android que lê um código de barras. Eu vi um vídeo no youtube que ensinava como fazer e repliquei para ter como base e funcionou de boas. O problema foi quando eu tentei colocar o retorno da leitura em um `EditText`. [No vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fo9haHF-PP0), o resultado aparece com `Toast`. Por mais que eu tente não aparece nada no `EditText`.

Segue o código Java:

```
package none.teste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

import static none.teste.R.layout.activity_menu;

public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

private ZXingScannerView leitorView;

    EditText editCodigo;

    Leitor l=new Leitor();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_menu);


        editCodigo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCodigo);
        Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"onCreate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
    public void LEITURA(View view) {

        leitorView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(leitorView);
        leitorView.setResultHandler(this);
        leitorView.startCamera();
        Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"LEITURA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        leitorView.stopCamera();
        Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"onPause",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        leitorView.stopCamera();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        l.setLido(result.getText().toString());
        editCodigo.setText(l.getLido());
        Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"handleResult",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        leitorView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"onResume",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Esses Toasts coloquei para saber por onde o aplicativo tava passando e a classe `Leitor` é besteira, só tem um atributo `String` com getter and setter, não precisa disso.
Enfim, queria passar o resultado para o `EditText`.

Comment: As vezes cometeremos erros bobos. Você se certificou se `result.getText().toString()` retorna algo?

Comment: Na verdade a solução pode esta exatamente ai, o texto que esta sendo informado em `editCodigo.setText(l.getLido());` vem de `result.getText().toString()`. Ele disse que o resultado aparece no Toast, mas na verdade só tem isso aqui: `Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"handleResult",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`.Com certeza deve verificar se Result, no método `handleResult` não esta vindo vazio.

Comment: Natan, me certifiquei sim, quando eu coloco  -> Toast.makeText(Menu.this,result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).s‌​how(); funciona de boas, mas o problema é que só funciona com Toast, quando tento colocar no edit com o setText este fica em branco, ou seja, tem um retorno, mas por algum motivo o negócio não aparece. Vale notar que se eu coloco setText com qualquer outra coisa, tipo editCodigo.setText("TESTE"); aparece TESTE no campo. Obrigado de qualquer forma. :) Acho que o problema tá no retorno pra activity_menu, mas não sei ao certo. Vou ver se consigo arrumar isso agr. Se souber algo fala aí

Comment: Glr, resolvi meu problema. O erro tava relacionado com a activity msm, tenho que mexer no manifest e outras coisas. Obrigado pra todos!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
editCodigo.setText("seu código de barras").
```

Isso permite que seu campo que já foi declarado na classe receba o valor que foi lido.

Comment: Rapaz, fico impressionado com a tendência atual que tenho percebido aqui de um pessoal que quer programar sem saber nada, nem o básico. Basta copiar e colar códigos de alguns lugares e, se não funcionar, por que não vir perguntar aqui como fazer as coisas...

Comment: Eu já tentei usar o setText, mas não acontece nada com o Edit, ele fica em branco, aparecendo no caso o Hint. Sei que esse comando funciona porque já usei em outros apps, até coloquei nesse dentro do onCreate que é executado ao iniciar o app, para ver o quen acontecia, e dae aparece o texto no Edit, mas não consigo colocar o resultado lá e não sei pq está acontecendo isso.

Comment: Você está usando o ZXingScannerView(). Quando respondi o tópico cheguei a assistir o vídeo mencionado e também a fazer algumas pesquisas. Nos artigo que havia encontrado vi algumas pessoas mencionando que já existe uma implementação nativa do google para leitura de código de barras. Tente encontrar algo assim. O tutorial pode estar defasado.